# Wanted to display 2 aggregation, but simpler

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently writing query and I have the following table:

| Continent | Location | Population | total_cases |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| North America | Canada | 38454328 | 4458946 |
| North America | Canada | 38454328 | 4476345 |

(I have omitted the date column, there is data for every single day)

I am looking to display the country, total_cases, and cases_per_capita (total_cases divided by population) that is grouped by country.

Here's the query that I wrote:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #latest_total_cases
CREATE TABLE #latest_total_cases
(
location nvarchar(255),
total_cases_max nvarchar(255)
)
INSERT INTO #latest_total_cases
SELECT location, MAX(CAST(total_cases AS int)) 
FROM CovidCasesAndDeaths
GROUP BY location

SELECT DISTINCT cnd.location, total_cases_max/population as cases_per_capita
FROM CovidCasesAndDeaths cnd
JOIN #latest_total_cases ltc
ON cnd.location = ltc.location
WHERE continent IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY cnd.location
```

The query above works, but I am pretty sure that there is a simpler way without using a temp table. I was stuck for a long time finding out how to display the final column cases_per_capita since population is not aggregated.

Comment: `SELECT location, MAX(total_cases)/max(population) as cases_per_capita FROM CovidCasesAndDeaths WHERE continent IS NOT NULL GROUP BY location ORDER BY location` should do the job. The only "Smell" here is that `max(population)` and `max(total_cases)` may come from two different records for a particular `location`, but I'm not sure if that something you care about or not.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @JNevill Thank you. But yes, I want the MAX(total_cases) to correspond with the population on the same row, confirming your concern.

Comment: In that case, how do you identify a unique row in this data. I'm afraid the screenshot and sample data is insufficient for determining that. Is it `continent`, `location` and some date or id column?

Comment: `location` and `date` should be the most unique. `date` especially, since the `max(total_cases)` will always be at the latest `date`

Comment: The problem refers to a very specific query and considers a specific case. It doesn't seem to match the type of common questions on this site

Answer (score 2):

When you're asking a question like this it's very helpful to provide proper and complete example DDL/DML:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (Continent NVARCHAR(20), Location NVARCHAR(20), Population INT, Total_Cases INT, Date DATE);
INSERT INTO @Table (Continent, Location, Population, Total_Cases, Date) VALUES
('North America', 'Canada', 38454328, 4458946, '2022-10-01'),
('North America', 'Canada', 38454328, 4476345, '2022-10-02');
```

While your assumption that the highest `Total_Cases` may hold true it's probably best not to rely on that, especially when you have a more appropriate way to determine the most recent row - the date column you describe.

```
SELECT t.Continent, t.Location, t.Population, t.Total_Cases, t.Date, 
       CAST((.0+Total_Cases)/(Population+.0) AS DECIMAL(5,2)) AS CasesPerCapita
  FROM @table t
    INNER JOIN (SELECT Continent, Location, Max(Date) AS mDate FROM @Table GROUP BY Continent, Location) md
      ON t.Date = md.mDate
      AND t.Continent = md.Continent
      AND t.Location = md.Location
```

| Continent | Location | Population | Total_Cases | Date | CasesPerCapita |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| North America | Canada | 38454328 | 4476345 | 2022-10-02 | 0.12 |

This code uses a self join on a subquery that aggregates on Continent and Location and determines the MAX date. The table is joined to the sub query using that date to return a single row, with the most recent date, and then performs the math on the total cases and population.

Comment: May I ask what `(.0+Total_Cases)/(Population+.0)' do? I am not yet familiar with this yet

Comment: @Reynal it just causes the values to implicitly cast as a decimal, so the result is a decimal. 9/4 is 2, while 9.0/4.0 is 2.25